# Formatting a UITableView Header

Tags: uitableview

I'm creating a custom header for my `UITableViewController`. The header that I'm creating is appearing underneath the current header and not replacing it. How do I change this so the default will be replaced or at least position my new header on top not underneath?

```
@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {
... 
}



@implementation RootViewController

 - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    return 40.0;

    }

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{



  CGFloat height = [self tableView: tableView heightForHeaderInSection: section];

    UIView *header=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(400,-10,300,height)];
    header.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];

    UILabel *headerLabel=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,300,30)];
    headerLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
    headerLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    headerLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0,1);
    headerLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor]; 
   headerLabel.text=@"Select";

    [header addSubview:headerLabel];

    [headerLabel release];
    return header;
}
```

The red is my custom and won't replace the blue header. 
[image]

Comment: i didn't get that why you have written header's Xpos as 400?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the "blue header" is a NavigationBar not a tableview header!

select your navigation controller and set TopBar to none if you dont want this blue bar ;o)

[image: Top Bar]

Comment: ha! oh dear. Thanks for the help! it's set to None so I guess I need to do something about the navigation view.

Answer (score 0):

Well it should work perfectly.Code contains no error.Are you sure its not working?